# How to make multi-level listview, that that contains custom linearLayout as Lucky Patcher?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'd like to make multi-level listview with custom layout, which is similar with the listview in Lucky Patcher App...

[image: Lucky Patcher]

How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExpandableListView is probably what you're looking for. Simply extend SimpleExpandableListAdapter and override its getView() method. Use your custom view for child views and you should be good to go. Finally set the ExpandableListView adapter to what you extended. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is good example. For me it takes modification, but the idea is clear.

[Custom Expandable ListView Tutorial - Android Example](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129)

The question can be considered closed.